# Discussing Exercise 10, section 4 on page 35 of Munkres’ Topology 2E

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In Ex 10, section 4 on page 35 of Munkres’ Topology 2E, the problem is stated as follows.

Ex 10
Show that every positive number $ a $ has exactly one positive square root, as follows:

(a) Show that if $ x>0 $ and $ 0≤h<1, $ then

$$ (x+h)^2≤x^2+h(2x+1), $$
$$ (x-h)^2≥x^2-h(2x). $$

(b) Let $ x>0$. Show that if $ x^2<a$, then $ (x+h)^2<a $ for some $ h>0$; and if $x^2>a$, then $ (x-h)^2>a$ for some $ h>0.$

(c) Given $ a>0$, let $ B $ be the set of all real numbers $ x $ such that $ x^2<a$.

Show that $ B $ is bounded above and contains at least one positive number. Let $ b=sup⁡\;B$; show that $ b^2=a$.

(d) Show that if $b$  and $ c $ are positive and $ b^2=c^2$, then $ b=c$.

Although there may be a similar question and answer, the following is my counter-part.

**Proof:**

(a) If $ x>0 $ and $ 0≤h<1$, then

$$(x+h)^2=x^2+h(2x+h)≤x^2+h(2x+1),$$
$$(x-h)^2=x^2-h(2x-h)≥x^2-h(2x).$$
(b) Let $ x>0 $ and $ x^2<a.$

Then by 9(d), we can choose $h$  such that $ 0≤h≤1$  and $  x^2<x^2+h(2x+1)<a. $ Then we get

$$(x+h)^2≤x^2+h(2x+1)<a.$$

Let $ x>0 $ and $ x^2>a$.
Then by 9(d), we can choose $ h $ such that $ 0≤h≤1$  and $ x^2>x^2-h(2x)>a$.
Then we get

$$(x-h)^2≥ x^2-h(2x)>a.$$

(c) Let $ a>0 $ be given and let $ B $ be the set of all real numbers $ x$ such that $ x^2<a$. Then it is clear that $  \sqrt{a}\;$  is an upper bound of $ B$. So, $B$ is bounded above. Since $ a>0$, by 9(d), there is a positive number $ z$ such that $ 0<z^2<a$.

Then $ z∈B$ implying that $ B$ contains at least one positive number. Let $ b=sup\;⁡B$, then it is clear that $ b>0$ and $ b^2≤a$ for $ \sqrt{a}\;$ is an upper bound of B. If $ b^2<a$, then by part (b), $(b+h)^2<a$, for some $ h>0$ implying that $ b+h∈B$, contrary to the fact that $b=sup\;⁡B$. Thus, $b^2=a$. That is, $ \sqrt{a}=b$.

(d) Suppose that $ b$ and $c$ are positive and $ b^2=c^2$, then $b^2-c^2=0$.
Thus, we get $ (b+c)(b-c)=0$. Since $b+c>0$ it follows that $ b-c=0$. That is
$b=c$.

Thus, we have proven that every positive number $a$ has exactly one positive square root.∎

I'd like to know whether my counter-part is valid or not. If not, please help me answer.

Note:

Exercise 9 on the same page goes as follows.

9. (a) Show that every nonempty subset of $ Z $ that is bounded above has a largest
   element.

(b) If $ x∉Z$, show there is exactly one $ n∈Z $ such that $ n < x < n + 1$.

(c) If $ x - y > 1$, show there is at least one $ n ∈ Z$ such that $ y < n < x$.

(d) If $ y < x$, show there is a rational number $ z$ such that $ y < z < x$.

Comment: You’re not allowed to use $\sqrt{a}$ in your answer since, you don’t know it exists yet!

Comment: It is also not clear that $b^2\le a$. At least, showing that would be some work in the proof - what goes wrong if $b^2>a$?